# RVM error: "Unknown ruby interpreter version" when trying to verify an .rvmrc file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm trying to set up my first .`rvmrc` file for one of my projects. I created a `.rvmrc` file in the root of the project folder with the following contents:

```
rvm 1.9.2p180@projectr3
```

Now when I list gemsets I'm asked to verify the file:

```
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p180 (found in /Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180)
   global
=> projectr3
   rails3
   ...

  ===============================================================
  = NOTICE:                                                     =
  ===============================================================
  = RVM has encountered a new or modified .rvmrc file in the    =
  = current working directory. Resource files may execute       =
  = arbitrary instructions, so RVM will not use an .rvmrc file  =
  = that has not been explicitly marked as 'trusted.'           =
  =                                                             =
  = Examine the contents of this file carefully to be sure the  =
  = contents are good before trusting it!                       =
  =                                                             =
  = You will now be given a chance to read the .rvmrc file      =
  = before deciding whether or not its contents are safe. After =
  = reading the file, you will be prompted 'yes or no' to set   =
  = the trust level for this particular version of the file.    =
  =                                                             =
  = Note: You will be re-prompted each time the .rvmrc file     =
  = changes, and may change the trust setting manually at any   =
  = time.                                                       =
  =                                                             =
  = Press 'q' to exit the reader when finished reading the file =
  ===============================================================

  (press enter to review the .rvmrc file)


rvm 1.9.2p180@projectr3


  Examining /Users/meltemi/rails/myproject/.rvmrc complete.

  ================================================================
  = Trusting an .rvmrc file means that whenever you cd into this =
  = directory, RVM will run this .rvmrc script in your shell.    =
  =                                                              =
  = If the contents of the file change, you will be re-prompted  =
  = to review the file and adjust its trust settings. You may    =
  = also change the trust settings manually at any time with     =
  = the 'rvm rvmrc' command.                                     =
  =                                                              =
  = Now that you have examined the contents of the file, do you  =
  = wish to trust this particular .rvmrc?                        =
  ================================================================

  (yes or no) > yes
ERROR: Unknown ruby interpreter version: '1.9.2p180'
bigmac:myproject meltemi$
```

What does this **ERROR: Unknown ruby interpreter version: '1.9.2p180'** mean?

FWIW - These are my rubies:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-rc2 [ x86_64 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a typo in your .rvmrc file.  Perhaps it should read:

```
environment_id="rvm 1.9.2-p180@projectr3"
```

I think you are missing the dash before the p180.

ian.

Comment: Whooops! Thanks for the fresh eyes!